# Ubuntu seems to have sizes mixed up

Tags: disk-usage

I've just tried to copy some files from one partition to another, and saw this:

[image]

And then checked What Pulse to see what I download normally.

[image]

As you can see, it seems to think there are 140.7 TB of files, when my Hard Drive is 2TB. And it seems to think I download 590309.46 TB daily, giving me an internet speed of 6.83 TB/s.

This isn't just a strange temporary glitch - it really won't let me copy it:

[image]

Despite it being just 10.7 GB:

[image]

Although when it first started scanning, it thought it was 140 TB:

[image]

Then jumps back down, and starts counting again:

[image]

What is the underlying issue, and can I fix it?

Comment: `/proc` .. why would you copy `/proc` and `/sys`? They don't have regular files and could easily cause confusion.

Comment: And if I did my experiment correctly, it will not stop copying from `/dev/zero` or `/dev/urandom` till space runs out.

Comment: Ahh so that's the issue? Do you know about the what pulse thing?

Comment: Sorry. No idea what What Pulse is.